# extracting data using php preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Im struggling to get this `PHP reg match` work.
I am loading file through `file_get_contents()` and my content will be like this,

```
                        <li  > 
                            <a href="http://www.example.org/index.php?id=2" >
                                Name AB 
                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li  > 
                            <a href="http://www.example.org/index.php?id=3" >
                                Name CD 
                            </a>
                        </li>
```

I want to get an array like

```
array('2' => 'Name AB'), array('3' => 'Name CD')
```

I have tried

```
preg_match("/([A-Z].*?[a-z].+)/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

It will only give me a name.

Thank you

Comment: never use regular expression to parse html use [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$link = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $link);
preg_match_all('/<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/si', $link, $result);

foreach($result[1] as $i => $data){
    $arr[] = array($i => $data);
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: it doesn't give me '2' => "Name AB" (id => name).
it only gives me href value